# rails devise - authentication google - can create but not login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I create a new account using google authentication, it creates a account and also do the login automaticaly.

If I click logout and later login again, with the same google account, I can't login...

I get no error message :(

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Google") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Another informations.

Here is the log when the autentication / account creation works:

```
Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:47:31 +0000


Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=1f3b3124e0264c1dabb3f40059d9a15a9da524553e0ec5dc&code=4/ZjqBwsoXJJXncItmMDuwPssw0ooT1RwnNjkRIfilQYc" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:47:33 +0000
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#google_oauth2 as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"1f3b3124e0264c1dabb3f40059d9a15a9da524553e0ec5dc", "code"=>"4/ZjqBwsoXJJXncItmMDuwPssw0ooT1RwnNjkRIfilQYc"}
  [1m[35mSubdomain Load (27.7ms)[0m  SELECT  "subdomains".* FROM "subdomains" WHERE "subdomains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "yoga"]]
  [1m[36mDomain Load (27.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["address", "smartmarket.io"]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (28.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "110174173081848856467"]]
  [1m[36m (27.7ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (27.8ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'diogowernik@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (27.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'diogowernik@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (27.9ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("provider", "uid", "name", "email", "image", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "really?"], ["name", "Diogo Wernik"], ["email", "diogowernik@gmail.com"], ["image", "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-vXjHRteu8BY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAB3A/_oEJPVq8h8o/photo.jpg"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$6CIsOntiZxoLQfyUTfskiuys3P4u6.M0O4h/4S5zoW7EpN2KgX4Re"], ["created_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.023034"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.023034"]]
  [1m[36mSQL (28.1ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "profiles" ("name", "kind", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["name", "Diogo Wernik"], ["kind", "blog"], ["user_id", 5], ["created_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.082199"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.082199"]]
  [1m[35mSQL (28.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "user_main_profiles" ("profile_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["profile_id", 5], ["user_id", 5], ["created_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.140877"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.140877"]]
  [1m[36mUserMainProfile Load (27.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "user_main_profiles".* FROM "user_main_profiles" WHERE "user_main_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 5]]
  [1m[35m (28.1ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36mUser Load (27.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35m (27.5ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (27.9ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_ip" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "sign_in_count" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7[0m  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.301029"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.301029"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "177.207.232.141/32"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "177.207.232.141/32"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.329926"], ["id", 5]]
  [1m[35m (28.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://yoga.smartmarket.io/
Completed 302 Found in 636ms (ActiveRecord: 418.1ms)
  [1m[36m (27.5ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (27.7ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."id" = $1  [["id", 11]]
  [1m[36m (27.9ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
```

Here is when i logout and try to login again with the same account

```
Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:51:13 +0000


Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=ca339595a33e9e192c274a78450400a02e7edfd7f7ebb937&code=4/bQ59Fm5Fcxv_vWtBlFpMAwMoY6iig8J6bZGWFKboZms" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:51:14 +0000
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#google_oauth2 as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"ca339595a33e9e192c274a78450400a02e7edfd7f7ebb937", "code"=>"4/bQ59Fm5Fcxv_vWtBlFpMAwMoY6iig8J6bZGWFKboZms"}
  [1m[35mSubdomain Load (27.6ms)[0m  SELECT  "subdomains".* FROM "subdomains" WHERE "subdomains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "yoga"]]
  [1m[36mDomain Load (27.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["address", "smartmarket.io"]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (27.9ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "110174173081848856467"]]
  [1m[36m (27.7ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (28.5ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'diogowernik@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (28.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'diogowernik@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (27.8ms)[0m  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://yoga.smartmarket.io/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 271ms (ActiveRecord: 195.0ms)


Started GET "/sign_up" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:51:15 +0000
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mSubdomain Load (27.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "subdomains".* FROM "subdomains" WHERE "subdomains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["address", "yoga"]]
  [1m[35mDomain Load (27.7ms)[0m  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "smartmarket.io"]]
  Rendered devise/registrations/_social.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_topnavbar.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_sidebar.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_alerts.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 251ms (Views: 165.2ms | ActiveRecord: 83.0ms)


Started GET "/api/i18n/site-pt.json" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:51:16 +0000
Processing by ApiController#i18n as JSON
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"site-pt"}
  Rendered app/assets/i18n/site-pt.json (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 5.8ms | ActiveRecord: 27.9ms)


Started GET "/assets/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:51:16 +0000


Started GET "/sign_up" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-10-23 23:51:16 +0000
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mSubdomain Load (27.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "subdomains".* FROM "subdomains" WHERE "subdomains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["address", "yoga"]]
  [1m[35mDomain Load (27.5ms)[0m  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "smartmarket.io"]]
  Rendered devise/registrations/_social.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_topnavbar.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_sidebar.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_alerts.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 231ms (Views: 144.7ms | ActiveRecord: 83.0ms)
```

Here is the user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Userable

  # include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable, :omniauthable # , :confirmable


  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  enum permission: [:guest, :admin]

  after_create :create_profile!, :send_welcome_email!
  before_validation :set_uid!

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
    end
  end


  def main_profile
    user_main_profile.try :profile
  end

  private

  def set_uid!
    self.uid = 'really?'
  end

  def create_profile!
    profile = profiles.create(
      name: name,
      kind: 'blog'
    )

    create_user_main_profile(profile_id: profile.id)
  end

  def send_welcome_email!
    UserMailer.delay.welcome(self.id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can tell is that your INSERT:

```
[1m[35mSQL (27.9ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("provider", "uid", "name", "email", "image", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "really?"], ["name", "Diogo Wernik"], ["email", "diogowernik@gmail.com"], ["image", "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-vXjHRteu8BY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAB3A/_oEJPVq8h8o/photo.jpg"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$6CIsOntiZxoLQfyUTfskiuys3P4u6.M0O4h/4S5zoW7EpN2KgX4Re"], ["created_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.023034"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-23 23:47:34.023034"]]
```

is passing field `["uid", "really?"]` when it should be passing `["uid", "110174173081848856467"]`

So when the user tries to log via Google, it searches:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "110174173081848856467"]]
```

Check your user.rb to see how omniauth is getting the variables or edit your post with the content.

Comment: Yes , you found the issue, but i could not find how to fix :) ... good, could you help me to find, i could not find out how to fix.. how to make it save the correct uid? I jus pasted the user.rb file...

Comment: Found the fix!!! Thanks a lot, i just deleted the set_uid , that i don't know why it was there and worked!!!